# 3.2 Apps with placeholder text will be rejected

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I I understand this question was asked already and its not specifically related to coding but I'm still confused.  I am getting my app ready for the apple app store. Now does this Guideline mean that all placeholder text in the storyboard should be blank. And all UILabels and UIButtons and UINavigationBar titles should be created programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It means that your running app can't contain placeholder text.

It's common for xib files or storyboards to contain various types of placeholders. That's ok as long as they are replaced when running the app.